# Extracting/Shifting bits in python for websocket RFC 6455

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to implement my own Websocket server in python im following the RFC 6455 Spec and im running into problems extracting the bits from the Base Frame header

im not having problems with the protocol im having problems with basic binary/hex math magic

according to the Specs the first 4 bits are single bit values

so to get the first bit i do something like this (d being my data from the websocket)

```
first_byte = ord(d[0])
print "finished bit",(first_byte >> 7) & 1
```

and later on if i want to get the payload size i do

```
sec_byte = ord(d[1])
print "payload size",sec_byte & 0x7f
```

however later in the spec i need to grab a 4bit value for the opcodes
this is what i need help on maybe even a link to how this math works ive googled/duckduckgoed my brains out most results being from stackoverflow

even more tinkering and its starting to fall into place i had been stuck on this for about 4 days now and still unsolved for anymore info anyone can give.

Comment: I suggest you try the `struct` module first. You are probably hitting endian-ness issues.

Comment: be sure to read the data as a stream with the intended "who is the most significant byte" according to the spec. In my answer, since you talked about just 4 bits and you've used ord, I supposed you have read everything as single octets "in sequence". And beware, `0x04` does not mean you are AND-ing 4 bytes! `first & 0x03` masks away all bits except "first" (LS) two bits from first, whatever first is.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to consider only the first (Most Significant) 4 bits, you need to right shift by 4 (extra masking with And could be unuseful, e.g. if your value is in the range 0-255, but it even stresses the bits  you're are interested in). E.g.

```
>>> d = [128, 80, 40]
>>> print (d[0] >> 4) & 15
8
>>> print (d[1] >> 4) & 15
5
>>> print (d[2] >> 4) & 15
2
```

128 is in binary `1000 0000`; right shifting by 4 gives `0000 1000` ("new" 0 bits enter from left), i.e. 8; 80 is `0101 0000`, so you obtain `0000 0101`; and finally 40 is `0010 1000` and we obtain `0000 0010`.

In general, consider an octet like `abcd efgh` where each letter is a bit. You have to shift and And in order to isolate the bits you are interested in. E.g. suppose your spec says `cd` bits define four different kind of something. In order to obtain that 0-3 number, you right shift by 4 again, and and with 3, that is `0000 0011`, i.e. you "isolate" the bits you want.

Comment: ive reread your comment about 60 times and i think its starting to click looks like im in for a long night of bits.

Comment: If you're saying it is not clear, I can try to make it clearer (but not now: I am going to leave for bed...) ... however, I think you need a little bit of bit fun to cope correctly with those tiny "units"...

Comment: yea its still a little fuzy but it helps if i draw it out. if you can add anything to help clear it up ill check back often.

Comment: maybe this reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation could help you? (if the problem is about bitwise operators; follows the links too, as bit manipulation, mask...)

Comment: thanks this did help some more ive actually decided to try and parse something a little more stable, Like a  bmp file and extract/modify the pixel data requires converting from little endian to big indian and back again. So i can get a grip on the concept in a more broader approach so i can come back to this and parse it with more understanding and not just hunting and pecking **at the bits** lol